# Using NDK to develop a game engine for android

Tags: java, c++11, android-ndk

I want to develop a 2D Game Engine, actually port an existing one. 
The existing one is written in C++, so I wanted to use C++ + NDK to be able to use existing code and only change the OpenGL, Sound and the input part of the code.
I was looking some solutions and I saw some people using SWIG, but is that the good solution.

The code is written in C++11, uses lambda, variadic template, function pointers, i don't know how well the SWIG will manage the code.
My Question is. Is it worth to try to modify the code to usee with SWIG or NDK (because it looks like i cannot use NDK to instantiate C++ classes, and probably variadic templates will be even worse). Should i drop the idea to just use Java and rewrite the Engine?

Comment: Look at NativeActivity - maybe you don't need any additional wrappers